# Time-Dependent Workflow rule not working

Tags: workflow, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

I have a time dependent workflow rule that doesn't work.

- Criteria: A case object's status is changed to "X" or "Y"
- after 3 days - send email alert
- after another 4 days - send another email alert
- after another 2 days - close case

WFR is activated.

Rule criteria is :

```
Case: Status EQUALS Need More Info,Customer to Verify
```

Evaluation criteria :

```
Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria
```

In the Monitor-time based workflows-queue - I see the correct cases, but when the time comes to send the email - nothing happens and later on the cases disappear from the queue, again - without any action taking place. Following steps also appear in the queue (3 entries for each case), but nothing happens to these cases, they remain unchanged.

[image: Time dependent workflow actions]

The email alert I'm using is defined to be sent to Email Field : Contact Email
[image]

Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing?
Please advise.

Comment: Silly question possibly, you're not in a sandbox are you? You might need to change your Deliverability settings under: Administer > Email Administration > Deliverability. Be careful doing this though as any e-mails that could send from the Sandbox will send to any and all e-mail addresses assuming you choose "All email", including your customers.

Comment: Would you please edit your post using the edit link at bottom left to show us who the alerts are sent to (what fields and objects are the send to's based on)? Make certain the templates are using the correct objects and related fields to send them along with a valid email address to send them from.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see your actual time triggers on the WFR.  are they set after the rule trigger date or are you using another date field for the time trigger?

Comment: Poet - I'm not in a sandbox. Checked the deliverability - it was already set to "All email". Jess

Comment: Jess C - I added an image to my post showing the time triggers - I'm using the rule trigger date (did try to use another date field (custom), but it didn't work...)

Comment: also worth checking is Salesforce email log (Setup | Email Administration ) to see if emails actually sent

Comment: crmprogdev - I edited my post and added an image showing the alerts. Is the field I'm using correct (Email Field : Contact Email)?

Comment: And another (basic) question : How do I know the email was sent? I was expecting to see it in the case itself, under the emails section. Is it true? it's possible that an email was sent and nothing is shown in the case object? I'm asking because in one of my tests I added another email alert to myself, and now I see that I do get this emails to myself, but they are not shown in the case object.

Comment: Emails triggered by workflows do not log an activity. Please see this KB article which also suggests a workaround: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005058&language=en_US

Comment: We had this same issue, so along with the email we created a completed task via workflow as well to indicate that an email should have been sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you describe:

1. You have a workflow with time-based email actions
2. The actions go into the queue
3. The actions are then removed from the queue but the email is not sent

If this is, in fact, the case, then this is a bug and should be reported as a case to support.

But in your notes, it sounds like *maybe* the emails are being sent, you just don't see them logged as activities. Is that actually what is happening?

If so, this is a known behavior (and currently the way this feature works). Take a look at this [KB article](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005058&language=en_US) in online help. In it, you will see the explanation, along with:

1. A suggested work around to also log a task as a second action on the same time trigger.
2. A link to the IdeaExchange idea that you can vote for to make this feature part of the platform.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I understand now that you are correct! I was expecting to see the emails as an activity in the case. Didn't know about the actual behavior. I entered the link, and also voted on the idea (sure would have saved me a whole lot of time...)